# List of the minimal addition chains

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, reference-request, computer-science, online-resources

The question of finding the Minimal Addition Chain (MAC) for needed for [Addition chain exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation) seems to be [NP-complete](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0210047). As such, it would be nice to have a list for the small powers already computed. Wikipedia lists the MAC's for $n\le16$. I'm looking for the known MAC's for $n>16$.

Comment: Maybe [reference-request] and [online-resources] tags are relevant.

Comment: @Srivatsan Agreed and updated, didn't even know about those tags!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://oeis.org/A003313 and references there, in particular the table up to n=10001.

Answer (score 3):

[This site about shortest addition chains](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/addition_chain.html) lets you generate a shortest addition chain for any number < 2^27, and lists a lot of interesting properties and references about them.

Comment: Thanks @DaveBall. Note that the reference is also in the OEIS link provided by RobertIsrael.